# How to pass function expression to lambda (sympy)

Tags: python, lambda, sympy

I don't know how to pass an expression to lambda parameter.
I think this is a problem of type with sympy.core.power.pow type.

Here is the code :

```
import sympy

def trapezoid(f, a, b, n):
    h = float(b - a) / n
    result = 0.5 * f(a) + 0.5 * f(b)
    for i in range(1, n):
        result += f(a + i * h)
    result *= h
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = sympy.Symbol('x')
    fonction = sympy.Pow(x,2)
    print(fonction) # x**2
    print(type(fonction)) # <class 'sympy.core.power.Pow'>

    print("Expected Result : ", trapezoid(lambda x: x ** 2, 1, 5, 100))

    print("Not expected result : ",trapezoid(lambda x:fonction, 1, 5, 100)) # Won't give me expected result
```

Have you guys any idea what is the correct syntax I need to use ?
I couldn't find an example of that even though I searched through several subjects.

Comment: I think you want `trapezoid(function, a, b, n)`

Comment: Many things are unclear here. What argument does `trapezoid` take? What arguments does `function` take? What do you mean by `print(function) # x**2` - is `function` just a string? `"x**2"`?

Comment: @PaulH or, more likely `trapezoid(function)`

Comment: Sorry about that. function is a mathematic expression and it's type is derived from the simpy lib. It's not a string. I actually tried lambda x:str(function) but it didn't work.
Other parameters don't really matter tbh

Comment: Please update your code with an [mcve] that includes the definition of the sympy function.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've updated the post so you guys can observe the problem yourself

Comment: I think you fundamentally misunderstand what you are doing here. The sympy object you created, `fonction = sympy.Pow(x,2)` is **not a function** or a callable object, so you cant use it like `fonction(value)`

Comment: So, what you *actually* want is a function, so `def function(x): return sympy.Pow(x, 2)` and then you can just use `trapezoid(function, 1, 5, 100)`

Comment: Problem is that I need to pass the expression of a function that is from that type (sympy.core.power.pow) to my lambda parameter.
Is there a way to convert it into an acceptable type ?

Comment: Your solution would work I think ( "def function(x): return sympy.Pow(x, 2)")  but I can't create it in advance in the code because this is something I get from a calculation depending on some user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating my answer based on the changes in your question -

Sympy lets you create expressions that can be utilized across multiple languages but you have to evaluate them when trying to run them. Your code's issue was that you were passing a sympy expression (which is NOT callable directly) to your trapezoid function. I have modified your trapezoid function to evaluate the 'fonction' you have defined.

```
from sympy import *

def trapezoid(f, a, b, n):
    h = float(b - a) / n
    result = 0.5 * f.evalf(subs={x: a}) + 0.5 * f.evalf(subs={x: b})
    for i in range(1, n):
        result += f.evalf(subs={x: (a + i * h)})
    result *= h
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = Symbol('x')
    fonction = Pow(x,2)
    print(fonction) # x**2
    print("Expected result : ",trapezoid(fonction, 1, 5, 100))
```

```
x**2
Expected result :  41.3344000000000
```

Check [this](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/numeric-computation.html) post out. Here you can find different ways of evaluating your sympy expressions in python.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've updated the post so it might be clearer now. I think this is a problem of type.

Comment: You sir are my hero. Thank you so much, it works as intended!

Comment: Glad to help. Also, just a note, you only need to define a symbol where you are defining an expression. Since you are defining it in your main, and passing it the function, you can skip symbol definition inside the trapezoid function.

Comment: You're right! Thank you for ignoring the change, I did that in my code and it works no problem.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp

The example below of how to create a lambda function and to call it.

```
my_func = lambda x: x**2;
print(my_func(3))
```

In your example:

```
def test(function):
    print(function)
    print(type(function))
    print(function(3))
```

Calling it:

```
>>> test(lambda x:x**2)
<function <lambda> at 0x7f49d24d7d50>
<type 'function'>
9
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've updated the post so it might be clearer now. I think this is a problem of type.